# Execute Cloud Flow in solution using Power Automate Web API

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-dynamics

Using the Power Automate Web API I can manage the cloud flows in solutions, however I also want to be able to execute flows. Is this possible through this Web API, or the Microsoft Dataverse Web API?

I can execute the flow if I use the url provided by the flow itself in an http request trigger, but I have no way to get or reverse engineer this url from the Power Automate API.

I have tried using the following:

https://myorg.myarea.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/workflows(workflowid)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ExecuteWorkflow

but to no avail. Take into account I use a client id and client secret to get an access token.

Comment: the url you posted is about classic worflows, not power automate flows. Which is the trigger or the power automate flow you want to execute?

Comment: If I copy the url in the flow:
https://prod-xxx.area.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/(flowid)/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=somesignature

It executes fine, BUT, my problem is how to get to this url. I don't want to copy it manualy for every flow. So I tried the other way.

Is there a way to get to this url from the API?

Comment: afaik not by Dataverse API

Comment: ok thanks. I used a different approach. I created an app with https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation rights and then with the user's permissions I call the api.flow.microsoft.com endpoint that supports this. This requires the user to sign in, but it is acceptable.

Comment: Hey @VassilisN.Perantzakis
Can you share more details on api you are able to call to execute flows.

Comment: @AbhishekGinani I posted a quick overview of the api i used as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick overview of my solution.

I first create an application in Azure with web authentication so I can use the redirection to get the login information and token.

Then I connect with oauth2 This requires a callback to get the token. The connection url looks like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope={0}&response_type=code&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&response_mode=query&state={3}
```

To get the flows of the team I call this using the token I get from the login process:

```
https://api.flow.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/Default-[EnvironmentId]/flows?api-version=2016-11-01&$filter=search(%27team%27)&$top=50&$expand=properties.connectionreferences
```

After that I parse the response, get the ids of the flows and for each I call:

```
https://api.flow.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/scopes/admin/environments/Default-[EnvironmentId]/flows/[FlowId]/runs?api-version=2016-11-01&$expand=properties/trigger
```

This will return among other things the triggerUrl and the name of the flow.

Hope this helps.